# On Heroku, how can i make boost libraries available for compiling a NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

My NodeJS app requires native C++ libraries for compilation (boost).

How can I make sure they are available at the build step?

*(So far I've tried buildpacks and, for debbuging, manually adding them via `heroku console`. Both to no avail.)*

Answer (score 1):

Check it [Customizing the build process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process), with `heroku-prebuild`, `heroku-postbuild`, etc to build your module.

Comment: I managed to load the files with a `heroku-prebuild` script, but how can they be made available to the npm build process? I suppose some environment variable has to be set ...

Comment: Are you use `node-gyp` ?

Comment: Yes. One error for example is `fatal error: boost/variant.hpp: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you build it success in local?

Comment: And your source can be public or not, I want test to check it

Comment: I do not yet have the environment set up for local testing. I tried `heroku config:add INCLUDE_PATH=...` and similar. Also I tried setting `include_dirs` in `binding.gyp`. Nothing seems to have any effect.